# ctx and guild parameter doesn't work in command and show error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have command custom_role:

```
@Bot.command()
async def custom_role(ctx, colour: str, *, name: str):
    colour = discord.Color(value=int(colour, 16))
    print(colour)
    await open_account(сtx.author)

    user = ctx.author

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if 1000>bal:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money")
        return

    await ctx.guild.create_role(name = name, colour=colour)

    await update_bank(user, -1000, "wallet")

    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name = name)
    
    await user.add_roles(role)

    emb = discord.Embed(description = "You bought custom role for a week!", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)

    await asyncio.sleep(604800)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

But I have two errors:

Undefined variable 'сtx'

Undefined variable 'guild'

Full traceback: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'сtx' is not defined

This is very weird, because in other commands ctx parameter works well

There are helper functions used in this command:

```
async def open_account(user):
    
    users = await get_bank_data()


    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    return True



async def update_bank(user, change = 0, mode = "wallet"):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    users[str(user.id)][mode] += change

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

    bal = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]

    return bal

async def get_bank_data():
     with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
         users = json.load(f)

      return users
```

If you know how to fix that, please answer

Comment: can and put the whole traceback?

Comment: What is `get_bank_data`?

Comment: full traceback: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'сtx' is not defined

Comment: ```get_bank_data``` is 
```async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users```

Comment: edit the question and put the tracenack and get_bank_data func in the question itself, don't put it in the comments lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command should be like this:

```
@Bot.command()
async def custom_role(ctx, colour: str, *, name: str):
    colour = discord.Color(value=int(colour, 16))
    print(colour)
    user = ctx.author
    await open_account(user)

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if 1000>bal:
        await ctx.send("You don't have that much money")
        return

    await ctx.guild.create_role(name = name, colour=colour)

    await update_bank(user, -1000, "wallet")

    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = name)

    await user.add_roles(role)

    emb = discord.Embed(description = "You bought custom role for a week!", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)

    await asyncio.sleep(604800)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

Because I forgot to put "ctx" before "guild.roles"